# Comment multiple lines shortcut in JavaScript, Domino Notes

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, xpages-ssjs, domino-designer-eclipse

Is there any shortcut to comment out JavaScript code in Notes?
I know the shortcut for Xpage is ctrl+shift+c

Comment: Which version of Domino Designer do you use?

Comment: @ChristophSchreiber  I'm using version 9, FP7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know your version of Domino Designer, so I can only provide a genearal answer to JavaScript comments.

If you only have **one line** you want to comment, just use `//` at the beginning of that line.

If you want to comment **multiple lines**, start the comment with `/*` and end it with `*/`.

Maybe you can find such a shortcut under Preferences --> General --> Keys (if your Domino Designer has that entry).

Comment: I'm using version 9, FP7. I did find a list of shout cut under General, thank a lot

Comment: Please share the shortcut with us. Other users will be happy to know the solution. @Kallen_Du

Answer (score 1):

if you use vscode mark all the lines you need to comment and then click

```
Ctrl + /
```

or add

```
//
```

to the beginning of every line.

Comment: You cannot use VS Code with Notes (unless you use AppDev Pack and node.js, but since OP mentions Xpages I doubt that is what he is using). For traditional Notes development you need to use Domino Designer.